# Are objects in array passed by reference?

Tags: php, arrays, object, reference

in a situation like that below,

```
class my_class {

    public __construct($params = array()){

        **** do something
    } 

 }

 $other_object = new some_class();

 $object = new my_class(array(
                         'var1' => 'test' 
                         'object' => $other_object));
```

**$other_object** will be passed by reference or by value?

Comment: That is easy to test for yourself: http://codepad.org/jo4FqQz1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Objects are always references, except you `clone` it explicitly.

You can use [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/spl-object-hash) to retrieve the "object id" and then compare them against each other. Remember, that once an object is removed from the memory by the garbage collector, the ID may get reused.

Comment: Strange, this was not be behaviour I was experiencing. `$tmp = $array[0]; $tmp['item'] = "something"; var_dump($array); \\ original values`

Comment: @WORMSS Whats the point? You modify `$tmp` and expect `$array` to change? Of course this doesn't work.

Comment: I would expect it to change, since as you just said Objects are references. And there is an object in $array[0].
You say "Of course this doesn't work" but I am coming back to PHP for the first time in 5 years from doing primarily javascript. Where if you do `var tmp = arr[0]; tmp['item'] = "something"; console.log(arr);` Arr[0] has been changed since the it is passed by reference.

I call it strange behaviour if you say objects are passed as references but this object in an array is acting like a value.

Comment: @WORMSS See https://3v4l.org/NEtno On the other hand you write `$tmp['item']` and so I don't believe you, that `$tmp` (or `$array[0]`) is _really_ an object, but a simple array. It could be an instance of a class implementing `ArrayAccess` of course, but I don't think so, am I right? As long as you don't show me, what `$array` is I can only guess. You can use 3v4l.org to show me an example of what you mean.

Comment: $array is an array. (hence the name). Is an array not an object in php?

Comment: @WORMSS No, it's a primitive type. But the actual question was: What is `$array[0]`?

Comment: Sorry, it was another associative array. But just knowing array is primitive answers all those questions. Like I said, I was coming back to PHP from doing Javascript for a LONG TIME, where arrays are objects. So I was not in the mindset that array in PHP was a primitive. Now I know, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I was having the exact problem. Really helpful discussion here.

Comment: It could be quite counter-intuitive to think arrays as primitive for someone more familiar with other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example that shows referenced object every where... http://codepad.org/HK6Oo4xL

Comment: did you wrote all that stuff by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Objects in php are passed by value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387949/functions-by-reference-or-by-variable-which-to-use-when/6388085#6388085) for details.

Comment: http://php.net/language.references The answer behind your link is something about "PHP doesn't have any references, because there are not like in C". Thats not wrong at all, but because PHP itself describes its understanding of references in its manual in detail, its wrong, when we just stay within the PHP-context. Lets say: An url is a reference to a website. Thats true, but from C's point of view its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in PHP 5 are always passed by reference. With the help of [debug_zval_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) you can check refcount for variable to calculate number of references to the object instance. Pay attention to the note in documentation, you will found many interesting things about passing a variable to a function.

Answer (score 0):

as of PHP 5 PHP object variable contain the reference or identifier to the actual variable. here is an example to demonstrate this.

```
class test{
public $test = 1;
}

$obj1 = new test;
$orginal = [$obj1,array(2),3];
$copy = $orginal;
echo 'orginal array';
var_dump($orginal);
echo 'copy of orginal';
var_dump($copy);

//after changing
$copy[0]->test = 'changed';
$copy[1][0] = 'changed';
$copy[3] = 'changed';
echo 'orginal array after changing its copy';
var_dump($original);
echo 'copy of orginal after changing';
var_dump($copy);
```

the output for this is

```
original array
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(test)[38]
      public 'test' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
  2 => int 3

copy of original
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(test)[38]
      public 'test' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
  2 => int 3

original array after changing its copy
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(test)[38]
      public 'test' => string 'changed' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
  2 => int 3

copy of original after changing
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(test)[38]
      public 'test' => string 'changed' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'changed' (length=7)
  2 => string 'changed' (length=7)
```

when the object in the copy is changed then the original object is also changed but the array and variable remain unchanged since they are passed as value.

more info about object reference refer :  [Objects and reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)