# Remove object reference from array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, reference

Im trying to copy array of objects to a new array. but the reference to the objects in the array are staying the same. my code :

```
$newArray = $this->ContentArray;
var_dump(newArray[0]->text); //print "text"
var_dump($this->ContentArray[0]->text); //print "text"
$this->ContentArray[0]->text = "edit text"; 
var_dump(newArray[0]->text); //print edit text"
```

how can I remove the reference to the objects?

Comment: Typo `$this-ContentArray[0]->text = "edit text"; ` must be `$this->ContentArray[0]->text = "edit text"; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitely clone each array element:

```
$newArray = array_map(
    function ($element) { return clone $element; },
    $this->ContentArray
);
array_merge($this->ContentArray,$newArray);

var_dump(newArray[0]->text);
var_dump($this->ContentArray[0]->text);
$this->ContentArray[0]->text = "edit text"; 
var_dump(newArray[0]->text);
```

But I prefer the solution from Praveen Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo: `$this-ContentArray[0]->text = "edit text";`

Should be `$this->ContentArray[0]->text = "edit text";`

**EDIT**
And you have tried putting '$' before newArray?

**EDIT 2**

It seems that Objects in PHP are always passed by reference, even if you. You might want to check out this thread:
[Passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608613/are-objects-in-array-passed-by-reference)