# How I can think about implement UML diagram with association between class and interface

Tags: class, inheritance, uml, associations, class-diagram

I'm try to think how I can understand this UML diagram and check how I can represent it to code:

[image]

What is make me confuse, we have an association relation between Company and Employee interface, and Designer classe is implement the Employee interface, but how we can connect Company with Employee interface?

What I understand (PHP for Example):

```
class Company {
 ...
}
class GameDevCompany extends Company {
 ...
}
class Designer extends GameDevCompany implements Employee {
 ...
}
```

If I think about this diagram like this code, its a truth way or I missing something or make something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is an Airbort? And which language are you using in that code snippet?

Comment: The code snippet just to preview code(pseudo), any language its not important, I need to understand the principle...
Airport is an super class  which need to manage company has plans in airport...
==========
I will edit question to add a new image from specific book

Comment: Well, every language is different. And you are using keywords defined in some language. How these keywords map is language specific. Also I was concerned about your type Air**b**ort which I assumed to be airport but that was not knowing. Would be nice to fix that in the UML and the code. That exra image is not needed.

Comment: Nice to know, Thank you! I will :tup:

Comment: Thank you for nice feedback, I update my to make sure its clear base on your recommendation, thank you

Comment: My PHP times ly in the far past now and it's late here too. I'll try to have a closer look tomorrow, but IIRC that looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have three concepts in this diagram:

- Specialization: a `Company` has two specializations which are `GameDev Company` and `Outsourcing Company`
- Realization:  an interface Employee can be realized by any class that implements this interface,  such as `Designer` (or `Programmer`, `Artist`, `Tester`, ...)
- Association:  a `Company` is associated with `Employee`.  The diagram does not say anything about multiplicity.  But since this is a very simple model, and based on our knowledge, we could guess that a Company may be associated with no, one, or several `Employee`.

In PHP terminology, specialization is [inheritance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php), which is expressed with the `extend` keyword:

```
class Company {
 ...
}
class GameDevCompany extends Company {
 ...
}
```

In PHP terminology [interfaces are implemented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) rather than realized and this is expressed with keyword `implements`

```
interface Employee {
 ...
}
class Designer implements Employee {
 ...
}
```

The association from one `Company` with potentially several `Employee` requires that `Company` has some kind of [iterable container](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) such as an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) that holds [references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to the `Employee` objects.  My PHP is very rusty,  but I understand that [objects in an array are always references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608613/3723423) which is exactly what is needed for ordinary associations.

Answer (score 1):

I just brushed up my rusted PHP knowledge and all I can say now is that your code is just fine. `extends` is inheritance (so the generalization relation to the left) and `implements` is interface implementation (so the realize relation to the right).

To extend on your query regarding the association: well, my PHP is very rusted, but IIRC it's completely untyped. So you will have some object pointer, say `$employee` in the `Company` class defined and that references objects having implemented the `Employee` interface. So you would probably do some `$employee->doWork()` in the `Company` class implementation. Likely you would not have a single one but an array. Honestly, that's really too long ago with the syntax. But you would probably know how to code that.

P.S. Since (as said) my PHP is very rusted I'm not so in the depth that I would know what the combination of `extends` and `implements` would produce.

Comment: Thank you for answer and for your time!, what about the associations relation between the Company and Interface, in our code, we need to add any something or specific code or its not needed since the relational is already done via Designer, this is meaning the arrow between Company and Interface?

Comment: Sorry, if my PHP knowledge is even rustier.  But doesn't `class Designer extends GameDevCompany implements Employee` mean that a `Designer` is a specialization of `GameDevCompany` and a realization of `Employee`?  This does not seem to correspond to the diagram in which `Designer` is just a realization of `Employee`   that is associated with a `GameDevCompany`...

Comment: @Christophe Honestly, your PHP isn't that rusted as mine. I was not looking in such depth but just saw the use of `extends` and `implements`. Maybe you can place an answer....

Comment: @qwerty_so thanks for this invitation :-)  Always happy to refresh a little bit my own memory ;-)

Comment: Really thank you all, Also I would like to add something, after reading more and more, I see this diagram build to represent the Factory Method Pattern, so, if we think like the factory method pattern we will find the answer like your explain in both answers, and the main idea for association if we use factory method pattern via access implemented method via realization or specialization, I think this example is very useful too: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/php/example#example-1